# cannot generate routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, named

i have a problem as following.

i have a resources setup in my routes.rb file as following

```
resources :users do
    resources :sub_transactions
end
resources :sub_transactions do
    collection do
        get :income
        get :expenditure
    end
end
```

Now what is the correct route that i should write so that i can generate the following routes

```
users/1/sub_transactions/income
users/1/sub_transactions/expenditure
```

where income and expenditure are not ids

Comment: Good point but he did only have 4 answers from 6 questions and some of those don't merit an acceptance (imo). It would be a shame if people have to accept incorrect or unhelpful answers just to get any more questions answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding those calls to the nested sub_transactions resource? Like:

```
resources :users do
  resources :sub_transactions do
    collection do 
      get :income
      get :expenditure
    end
  end
end
```

I'm not in a position to test at the moment but that would be the logical starting point (I figure).